# Proof verification for every real number is both an upper bound and lower bound for an empty set.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}$. There is no element $e$ in an empty set such that $e \gt M$. It follows that all elements in empty set must be less than $M$. Similarly, we can't find any element $e$ in an empty set such that $e < M$. Hence, $M$must be the lower bound for the empty set.

Comment: this is correct.  And it leads to the deeply unintuitive statement that the least upper bound for the empty set  is $-\infty$ and the greatest lower bound is $+\infty$.  Worth noting that using this convention has the nice property that the least upper bound of $A\cup B$ is the greater of the two upper bounds, and similarly for greatest lower bound.

Comment: It helps if you think of element $e$ as _a_ lower bound, not _the_ lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly common is to define $$\inf \varnothing := + \infty$$ and $$\sup \varnothing := -\infty$$ which is incorporated by your (correct) proof.